# How to give the multiple attributes order in ASC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-order-by

I am new to ruby on rails. I am trying to do show the tasks based on `position` number and also `row_order`, row_order for to set the order of the task when drag and drop. Position of the task used for add above the task and add below the task. For `row_order` i'm using `ranked model gem`.

```
= render '/task_list', tasks: @project.tasks.incomplete.order( "position ASC, row_order ASC")
```

i am trying in this way but it's working only for 1st attribute if it is `position` or `row_order`

tasks table

```
+------------------------------+
| id  |  row_order | position   |
+------------------------------+
| 1   | 1048577     | 1        |
| 2   | 7602176     | 2        |
| 3   | 8126464     | 3        |
+------------------------------+
```

`row_order` will change when task gets drag and drop. `position` won't change when task gets drag

**After drag the tasks**

```
+------------------------------+
| id  |  row_order | position   |
+------------------------------+
| 1   | -2068477    | 1        |
| 2   |  7602176    | 2        |
| 3   | -5242879    | 3        |
+------------------------------+
```

Comment: When you do order by two fields, it will order them all by the first field, and if there are any with the same first field, they'll be ordered by the second field. I don't understand what you mean by "but it's working only for 1st attribute if it is position or row_order", can you explain some more, maybe with some examples?

Comment: @MaxWilliams i.e `.order("position ASC") or .order ("row_order ASC").

Comment: Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

Comment: @MoisesZaragoza Earlier i followed this but not working. Thank you.

Comment: @Mani can you post the controller. I just want to see what is it that you are doing

Comment: @MoisesZaragoza i don't have permission for that.

Comment: @Mani try `= render '/task_list', tasks: @project.tasks.incomplete.order(position" :asc).order(row_order: :desc)`

Comment: @MoisesZaragoza i am trying with this. Only work for `position` not for `row_order`. `= render 'tasks/task_list', tasks: @project.tasks.incomplete.order(position: :desc).order(row_order: :asc)`

Comment: have you tried it on the console? and are `position` and `row_order` in the same model?

Comment: @MoisesZaragoza Yes. Both are in same model.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example from the source http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

```
Client.order(orders_count: :asc, created_at: :desc)
# OR
Client.order(:orders_count, created_at: :desc)
# OR
Client.order("orders_count ASC, created_at DESC")
# OR
Client.order("orders_count ASC", "created_at DESC")
```

or you can do

```
Client.order("orders_count ASC").order("created_at DESC")
# SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY orders_count ASC, created_at DESC
```